# How does one incorporate Boolean logic in defined functions?

Tags: boolean-logic

I have got this to work but I am trying to intuitively understand how the if (see below...has_botton_and_top)statement works in this instance.. i.e how the boolean logic works :

```
def cylinder_surface_area(radius, height,has_top_and_bottom ):          
side_area = height * 6.28 * radius    
if has_top_and_bottom:          
  top_area = 2*3.14 * radius ** 2        
  return (side_area + top_area)     
else:return side_area 

print(cylinder_surface_area(10,5,False))
```

Comment: Do you have prior experience with any other language, or is Python the first language you have used? What resources are you trying to use to learn Python? It sounds as if a stronger basis in coding concepts would be useful before you try and dive right in.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, way back I dabbled a little in COBOL and BASIC and am now picking up after more than 30 years. Is it because in Python we don't have to initially declare the (variable) parameter type and therefore when I say "if  parameter..."  and subsequently use the defined function with variable using an  input True or False it automatically treats it as Boolean. Don't know if this makes sense? Thanks again.

Comment: @quixotrykd.. As a novice I am trying to use freely available resources on MOOCs(Udacity/edX/Coursera). I have also downloaded Atom and Script to be able to run code in an editor. Your suggestions resources which are greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Python a whole lot, but when I do I really like using the Python IDLE editor. It gives you a pretty bare-bones editor for your code, that you can execute very easily. In terms of editor, it is entirely a matter of preference. As long as the editor that you are using suits all of your needs and you can use it, it is the best editor for you.

Now, in reference to your question: I can definitely understand where your confusion comes from. The way that Python treats variables(and consequently does not require strict typing of variables) was confusing for me at first as well. From the Python documentation,

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> None False zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j. any
>   empty sequence, for example, '', (), []. any empty mapping, for
>   example, {}. instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>   __nonzero__() or __len__() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. All other values are considered true
>   -- so objects of many types are always true. Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for
>   false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important
>   exception: the Boolean operations "or" and "and" always return one of
>   their operands.)

Thus, your function is expecting for you to enter a Boolean input, however even if you enter a String, an Integer, a Double, or anything else it will still be able to evaluate all of these with well-defined behavior. I am assuming that your confusion comes from the fact that you can evaluate any variable as True or False, and not how Boolean logic works at its core. If you need me to explain Boolean logic as well, feel free to comment and I'll add that too.

Comment: @RBU if it helped you out, please accept it so that it can help others out.

Comment: @RBU no worries! It was a good question. I'm glad that I could help you out